# $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-\cos (1-\cos (1-\cos x))}{x^{a}}$ is finite then the max value of $a$ is?

Tags: limits

I know the formula $\frac{1-\cos x}{x^{2}}=\dfrac{1}2$

But how do i use it here and tried l hospital and no use and doing l hospital twice will make it very lengthy how do i approach ?

Comment: Have you tried Taylor series?

Comment: @ClementC. Im new to taylor series but i will learn it asap .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. 
$$ \frac{1 - \cos\bigl(1 - \cos(1-\cos x)\bigr)}{x^a} 
 = \frac{1 - \cos\bigl(1 - \cos(1-\cos x)\bigr)}{\bigl(1 - \cos(1 - \cos x)\bigr)^2} \cdot \left(\frac{1 - \cos(1 - \cos x)}{(1 - \cos x)^2}\right)^2 \cdot \frac{(1 - \cos x)^4}{x^a} $$

Comment: Didn't think about that possibility thank you so much .

Comment: @SujithZis: That possibility came from understanding asymptotic behaviour, which usually is obvious and more natural via Taylor series.

Comment: @user21820 taylor series seems fun will learn it asap , thanks .

Comment: @SujithZis: Refreshing to hear people call mathematical stuff fun. =)

Answer (score 4):

Using Taylor series: when $x\to 0$, we have
$\cos x = 1-\frac{x^2}{2} + o(x^2)$.
Step by step, we can use this as follows:
$$
1-\cos x = \frac{x^2}{2} + o(x^2)
$$
so that, plugging it back:
$$
\cos(1-\cos x) = 1-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x^2}{2} + o(x^2)\right)^2 = 1-\frac{x^4}{8} + o(x^4)
$$
and therefore
$$
1-\cos (1-\cos x) = \frac{x^4}{8} + o(x^4).
$$
One more time:
$$
\cos(1-\cos (1-\cos x)) = \cos(\frac{x^4}{8} + o(x^4)) = 1 - \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{x^8}{64} + o(x^8)
$$
leading to
$$
\frac{1-\cos(1-\cos (1-\cos x))}{x^a} = \frac{\frac{x^8}{128}+o(x^8)}{x^a}
$$

Note that here, expanding to the second order $\cos x = 1+\frac{x^2}{2} + o(x^2)$ was enough for the "composition of Taylor series" to work; and that the whole approach relies on the fact that when $x\to0$, then $x^k\to 0$ (for $k=2$ and $k=4$), so that we have $\cos(\alpha x^k) = 1-\frac{(\alpha x^k)^2}{2}+o(x^{2k})$.

Comment: Also, on a side note, the Taylor approximation used here (to order $x^2$) is exactly equivalent to the limit you know: $\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2} \xrightarrow[x\to 0]{} \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Awesome i will try to remember your generalised formula instead of my old one , thank you so much.

Comment: @SujithZis [$\cos x = 1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^6}{6!} +\dots+\frac{(-1)^k x^{2k}}{(2k)!} + o(x^{2k+1})$.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions)

Answer (score 1):

You could try to approach this problem using Taylor series:
$$\text{cos}(x) = 1-\frac{x^2}{2}+O(x^4)$$
So 
$$\text{cos}(1-\text{cos}(x)) = \text{cos}\left(\frac{x^2}{2}+O(x^4)\right) = 1-\frac{\left(\frac{x^2}{2}+O(x^4)\right)^2}{2}+O(x^4)$$
$$ = 1-\frac{x^4}{8}+O(x^4)$$
And so on...